# Using Apache htaccess and PHP, how can I route requests to non public directories?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a web structure like

```
php/
public_html/ 
   .htaccess
```

How can I route anything to

```
www.mywebsite.com/app/
```

to my actual php controller

```
php/App.php
```

So far I have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^app/*$ ./php/App.php?*
```

But this is wrong because

1. The directory to App is wrong. Not sure how to move to move up to the `/php` dir
2. I need to pass all request params (GET and POST) to App.php but I'm not sure how, i tried `?*`

Answer (score 2):

A better and more common approach is to create an `index.php` in your `public_html` directory where you include PHP scripts from your `php` directory which is above the web root.

Good frameworks like Laravel use this approach. Here you can see [Laravel's .htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess).

And you can use `GET` and `POST` just you would normally do.

Comment: Isn't this bad? I thought I must keep my PHP out of public. If I put App.php into public_html, and it has includes (with file paths of course) to things like Users.php etc, doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: @user3822370 - no, it doesn't defeat the purpose. The code is included into the index file for execution purposes. So long as your code is above the web root, nothing can access it but the index file. So this is the correct approach. In fact, there is no other way to reference your code, as `.htaccess` cannot see above the directory it resides in.

Comment: Just to clarify something: the use of an index file, in this case, is known as *bootstrapping* as it loads the necessary stuff for your application to run - thus *booting* it. In the Laravel world, the bootstrapper is somewhat complex and uses Autoloading etc.

Comment: Thanks.. so my question still stands then - how do I route all traffic using htaccess? I want all requests to mysite.com/app/ to go to mysite.com/app.php including all post and  get